# Laravel init query for multiple usage

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have this init of query in my model:

```
$query = Mymodel::where('is_active', 1);
```

i use it to get different result:

```
$result1 = $query->where('stat', null)->count();
$result2 = $query->where('stat', '!=', null)->count();
```

i have 4 rows in my database, 2 of them have stat null and 2 is not null; so i expect that $result1 and $result2 value are 2; but i got that $result1 is 2 and $result2 is 0;

as if the $result2 query has the 2 conditions null and not null;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really use the same query like that. The `where` clauses will modify the original `$query` object, so your counts will be a little off.

You should either clone the original, or define it as a Scope:

`clone` Approach:

```php
$baseQuery = Mymodel::where('is_active', 1);

$result1 = (clone $baseQuery)->whereNull('stat')->count();
$result2 = (clone $baseQuery)->whereNotNull('stat')->count();
```

`scope` Approach:

`Mymodel.php`:

```php
public function scopeActive($query) {
  return $query->where('is_active', 1);
}
```

Then in your code:

```php
$result1 = Mymodel::active()->whereNull('stat')->count();
$result2 = Mymodel::active()->whereNotNull('stat')->count();
```

Comment: My 2 cents for current OP or future readers - use the scope approach. Using the clone approach will work fine, but has the higher chance of future bugs if a dev modifies things without fully understanding why the clone is needed.

Comment: @BrianThompson 100% agreed! I added the `clone` approach to attempt to illustrate why they were getting the results (from their suspicion, *"[...] as if the `$result2` query has the 2 conditions `null` and `not null`"*), but using a scope is definitely the preferred approach. Cheers!